# How to share the common parts of two models in pytorch？

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I had a problem implementing the model with pytorch.

I want to build two models, some of which are shared, and share the encoder part like this

```
Model1: input_1 -> encoder -> decoder_1 -> ouput_1
Model2: input_2 -> encoder -> decoder_2 -> ouput_2
```

What I want to do is make the two models use the encoder part together, but the decoder part is not the same. I looked up about parameter sharing, but it seems to be somewhat different from the requirements here.

My own idea is to build a model that includes encode, decoder_1, decoder_2 and then choose which decoder to use based on input.

I'm not sure about this method, if possible, can you give simple examples for using the common parts of two models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```py
import torch.nn as nn

class SharedModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, mode):
        super(SharedModel, self).__init__()
        self.mode = mode # use 1 or 2

        self.encoder = ...
        self.decoder_1 = ...
        self.decoder_2 = ...


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        if self.mode == 1:
            x = self.decoder_1(x)
        elif self.mode == 2:
            x = self.decoder_2(x)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unkown mode.")
        return x
```

Comment: Is mode a little better in the forward function than in an initialization function? Because there are two kinds of data entered during training.

Comment: @DirkLi you can change the mode easily with `model = SharedModel()` and then set `model.mode = 1 # or 2` whenever the operation mode needs to change

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make one `SharedModel`, would rather go for two, but sharing `encoder` part.

```
import torch

class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder: torch.nn.Module = encoder
        self.decoder: torch.nn.Module


    def forward(self, x):
        return self.decoder(self.encoder)

encoder = ...
decoder1 = ...
decoder2 = ...
first = Model(encoder, decoder1)
second = Model(encoder, decoder2)
```

You could also split `Model` class, but in essence, pass encoder as argument to constructor and it will be shared between as many models as you like.

No need for `if`, custom `mode` and others workarounds. Furthermore it's input independent, no way to accidentally pass wrong input and get the result.